# Package when using the Turtle module will not download

Tags: python

I've been using the turtle package for months however when I cam to use it this morning I had the error message:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified
```

After getting this message I've attempted 101 different ways to install turtle, even using a different application to what I normally use and it still won't work. When I try to install it through the terminal I am receiving the message:

```
C:\Users\joeca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts>pip install turtle
Collecting turtle
  Using cached turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\joeca\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-quqzd5f6\turtle_0ebb0257dfa4462295fda2a9f448e31c\setup.py", line 40
          except ValueError, ve:
                           ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Has anyone else had this issue before and if so how can I fi this as I use turtle very often in order to make projects.

Comment: I have also followed this video: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paRXeLurjE4) to help but it's made no difference.

Comment: if you mean module [turtle graphics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) then it should be installed with `Python` and you can't install it with `pip`. If you don't have it then you have to reinstall `Python`. And error suggest that you try to install some module created for `Pythn 2` and it will NOT work with `Python 3`. And this `turtle` doesn't have to be `turtle graphics`.

Comment: based on page [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/search/?q=turtle) you try to install `"Turtle is an HTTP proxy whose purpose is to throttle connections to specific hostnames to avoid breaking terms of usage of those API providers (like del.icio.us, technorati and so on)."` and last version was created in 2009

Comment: Sorry. So do you recommend I just fully reinstall python and try to reinstall it then or what is your suggested solution?

Comment: my solution is to install Python againg because `turtle graphics` is installed only with Python and you can't install it with `pip`

Comment: BTW: you should show FULL error message maybe it shows what path it can't find - maybe you renamed it - and then it may need only rename it back. But if you deleted it then only reinstalling Python can help.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know. Also, It was literally just a case of reinstalling python haha. I've been sat here for like 4hours trying to figure out my issue when all I had to do was reinstall python and change my interpreter. Thanks for the help!